# Count element with Style Val = 0?

Tags: jquery, count

I was wondering how to count a list of `<li>` with a style val = 0 ?

i.e. something like

```
jQuery('ol.myClass li').each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).css('top') == '0px') {
        count = + 1;
    }
});
```

How would I do this so it finds all elements and gives me a figure for all those that have the val = 0 for `css('top')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks good.

But your count should be:

```
$count += 1;
```

or

```
$count++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var foo = $('ol.myClass li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('top') == '0px';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say try this way.

```
var list = $("ol.myClass li").filter(function() { 
  return $(this).css("top") === "0px";
});

list.length
```